Use HTTPS with Gitlab in Docker Container
I have a Docker Container with Gitlab running on a server on the Internet. It is connected to a subdomain (gitlab.example.com) using Nginx on the host system. Incoming calls to https://gitlab.example.com are then "proxy_pass" to the Docker Container at http://localhost:8081. Keep in mind the change from the exterior HTTPS to the internal HTTP. This setup works perfectly fine, but has one step missing. Gitlab itself thinks it is in use of HTTP and not HTTPS, meaning that when I want to get the Url to one of the projects, Gitlab will return a path like this http://gitlab.example.com/myuser/myproject.git. The path will not work because of the http://... instead of https://.... Therefore, to still make use of this path i.e. for using git clone ..., I will have to manually change it from http://... to https://... which doesn't kill me, although it is worth being setup correctly.
What are the steps necessary to let Nginx return the "correct" Url with https://... instead of http://...?

Hi! Did you look at the documentation? https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#service-specific-nginx-settings
